# Where Clause in SQL QUERY

Tags: sql

How to add not equal to operation in then clause ?
For Example

```
@Sample varchar(50)


Select * from table
Where 
ISNULL(table.column1, '') = CASE WHEN @Sample = '1' THEN '500' 
                                 WHEN @Sample = '0' THEN '600' 
                                 ELSE (NOT EQUAL TO 500)
                            END
```

Comment: What do you want to return in place of `NOT EQUAL TO 500`?

Comment: i want to return all the results whch is not equal to 500..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `CASE` expression:

```
select * from  table
where
    (@Sample='1' and table.column1 = '500') or
    (@Sample='0' and table.column1 = '600') or
    (@Sample not in ('0','1') and COALESCE(table.column1,'') <> '500')
```